# PPML package gravity with time fixed effects

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to include time fixed effects (dummies for years generated with model.matrix) into a PPML regression in R.

Without time fixed effect the regression is:

```
require(gravity)
my_model <- PPML(y="v", dist="dist", 
            x=c("land","contig","comlang_ethno",
            "smctry","tech","exrate"), 
            vce_robust=T, data=database)
```

I've tried to add command `fe=c("year")` within the PPML function but it doesn't work.

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3):

I would comment on the previous answer but don't have enough reputation. The gravity model in your PPML command specifies *v* = *dist* × exp(*land* + *contig* + *comlang_ethno* + *smctry* + *tech* + *exrate* + *TimeFE*) = exp(log(*dist*) + *land* + *contig* + *comlang_ethno* + *smctry* + *tech* + *exrate* + *TimeFE*).

The formula inside of `glm` should have as its RHS the variables inside the exponential, because it represents the linear predictor produced by the link function (the Poisson default for which is natural log).  So in sum, your command should be

```
glm(v ~ log(dist) + land + contig + comlang_ethno + smctry + tech + exrate + factor(year), 
      family='quasipoisson')
```

and in particular, you need to have distance in logs on the RHS (unlike the previous answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that `year` is a factor, than you can just use the plain-and-simple `glm`-function as

`glm(y ~ dist + year, family = "quasipoisson")`

which gives you the results with `year` as dummies/fixed effects. The robust SE are then calculated with

`lmtest::coeftest(EstimationResults.PPML, vcov=sandwich::vcovHC(model.PPML, "HC1"))`

The `PPML` function does nothing more, it just isn't very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `PPML` and `glm`, you can also solve your problem using the function `femlm` (from package `FENmlm`) which deals with fixed-effect estimation for maximum likelihood models.

The two main advantages of function `femlm` are:

- you can add as many fixed-effects as you want, and they are dealt with separately leading to computing times without comparison to glm (especially when fixed-effects contain many categories)
- standard-errors can be clustered with intuitive commands

Here's an example regarding your problem (with just two variables and the year fixed-effects):

```
library(FENmlm)
# (default family is Poisson, 'pipe' separates variables from fixed-effects)
res = femlm(v ~ log(dist) + land | year, base) 
summary(res, se = "cluster")
```

This code estimates the coefficients of variables `log(dist)` and `land` with `year` fixed-effects; then it displays the coefficients table with clustered standard-errors (w.r.t. `year`) for the two variables.

Going beyond your initial question, now assume you have a more complex case with three fixed-effects: `country_i`, `country_j` and `year`. You'd write:

```
res = femlm(v ~ log(dist) + land | country_i + country_j + year, base)
```

You can then easily play around with clustered standard-errors:

```
# Cluster w.r.t. country_i (default is first cluster encountered):
summary(res, se = "cluster") 
summary(res, se = "cluster", cluster = "year") # cluster w.r.t. year cluster
# Two-way clustering:
summary(res, se = "twoway") # two-way clustering w.r.t. country_i & country_j
# two way clustering w.r.t. country_i & year:
summary(res, se = "twoway", cluster = c("country_i", "year"))
```

For more information on the package, the vignette can be found at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FENmlm/vignettes/FENmlm.html.